# ASP.Net Ajax client side script, accessing source

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I've seen in quite a few examples of asp.net ajax client side script the following:

```
function fHelloWorld(source, eventArgs)
{

}
```

If I run an alert on the source it's returned as an object. Can I use this to access what called the function? And if so how? i've tried things like

```
source.id;
```

Without luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best advice that I can offer is, given an object, enumerate over the properties and write them out, including their values to the page. Then inspect the property values and will surely find out if such a property exists. You could also use [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com), [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) or host of other tools to inspect the object.

Here's an example

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {

// add function to the PageRequestManager to be executed on async postback initialize
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
      prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);   
}


function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
    // Display loader gif when async postback initialized by element_in_question
    if(args._postBackElement.id === 'id_of_element_in_question' {              
        $get('ajax-loader').style.display = 'inline';
    }         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the page with Firefox & Firebug, [set a breakpoint](http://getfirebug.com/js.html) inside your function, and inspect the `source` object interactively.

You can also display the object with `console.log` to get an object inspection hyperlink:

```
function fHelloWorld(source, eventArgs)
{
  console.log("%o", source);
}
```